# adding numbers in a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string of numbers, for example 12458960. How can I go about adding them so that it would be 1+2+4+5+8+9+6+0 = 35

I have the numbers already recorded into a variable called ccn. I just need to get the sum now. I tried adding the string numbers using,

```
ccn[0]+ccn[1]+ccn[2]+ccn[3]+ccn[4]+ccn[5]+ccn[6]+ccn[7]
```

But that didnt work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried. You must have more code than: `ccn[0]+ccn[1]+ ...`

Comment: Also add what is wrong or what error you are getting. I have a feeling that error could lead you to the solution...

Comment: If all the elements of string are numbers then try this `sum(map(int,num))` else look at @Tomerikoo 's comment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help everyone, I managed to sort this one out, but will take note of your comments for future notice!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:-

```
a = '12458960'
res = sum(map(int, a))
print(res)
```

Output:-

```
35
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one liner:

```
a = '12458960'
print (sum(int(i) for i in a))
```

Comment: Probably as well to use Python 3 style print syntax now that Python 2 is obsolete

Comment: this worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic way:

```
num = '123458960'
number = 0
for n in num:
    number += int(n)
print(number)
```